# Understanding how to create django Models

Tags: django, model

I followed some examples on the Django website and I understand the idea that Django wants you to separate pieces of the project into 'apps'.

Each 'app' has its own models. So if I want to create an app that allows users to login and modify some data (add/edit/delete), like a collection of books and collection of authors, I need to create apps for this.

In this case I would have an 'app' **books**
that contains `models.py`, with two model classes : `Book` and `Author`. The `Book` class would have as one of its fields `author = models.ForeignKey(Author)`.

So here are my questions:

1. If I create a new `app` can my models in that app contain ForeignKey fields to models that don't reside in the same `app`?
2. As I mentioned, I want to have a credentials 'table' that allows users to login. How could this be accomplished? Is it necessary to start a new 'app' like 'users' with a user model?
3. How does one incorporate MySQL features like 'auto increment', 'non-unique index', and 'triggers' into these modesl or does that have to be done manually or through a MySQL console/manager?

Comment: If one of the answers below has fully answered your question, please go ahead and accept it.  Otherwise, let us know what we can do to clarify.

Comment: Haha - that means the system is working.  Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from making relationships to models in other apps.  Apps are simply are a way to group code in logical places.  Here is an example of how you might reference one model located in a different app.

Say this is in a module called myapp, you can refer to other models in other apps with syntax similar to the following.  In this example, there exists a User model inside of an "auth" app.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ....
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

Also see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Django has a great and flexible user system that comes built into it.  When you start a new project, by default, it will create a User table that can be used to create, manage, and authenticate users.

Here is some related [information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/).  (Actually, the example above shows a relationship to the built-in user table.)  You don't have to start a new app for defining Users unless you want to customize the default behavior of the user framework.

Django automatically increments primary key fields records.  It creates necessary database objects needed for this.  It also enforces unique fields if desired and allows a bunch of other customizations.  As far as I'm aware, Django does not support database triggers.  I believe that the "Pythonic" way to trigger things may be to do so in your code.  Specifically, Django/Python would manage what actions are take after others.  That's just my thoughts, though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. See this SO question: [Foreign key from one app into another in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323763/foreign-key-from-one-app-into-another-in-django)
2. You can use Django's built-in auth app and User object for this.  It's one of the "batteries included" features.  See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/).
3. I don't
   have as much experience with MySQL specifically, but some of the
   things you mention are built into the ORM.  I.e. auto-increment
   happens automatically with a default id field if you don't specify a
   different primary key ([AutoField reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField)).  [Non-unique indices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.index_together) were added as of Django 1.5. Triggers seem a little trickier, but [this blog post](http://bryanmarty.com/blog/2012/12/03/mysql-triggers-django/) looks like a nice write-up.

As an aside, the [Django aggregation topic guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) uses Author and Book models as the primary examples.

Comment: Just as a side note on bullet #1 - One of the features Django boasts is "pluggable apps". Basically what
    that means is that I should be able to take your `Books` app and
    plug it into my own `Library` app and it should work straight out
    the box. If you have an app referencing some other app then you've
    successfully coupled the `Books` app to this other app and you have
    no way of decoupling them. This is one of the
    downsides when making a bigger system with Django, there is no
    evident "business logic layer" if you want to call it that.

Comment: @limelights You are totally correct but I don't think the two (pluggable apps vs. interdependencies) are mutually exclusive. On a large company project there might be a few interdependent apps that are never intended to be released to the public but which are clearer logically if split up (to avoid having multi-thousand line models.py files). Every effort should be made to keep things reusable, but if the whole project will be more maintainable with logical division, I think it's worth it.  Often you can see if an app might lend itself to reusability while writing it and design accordingly.

Comment: A better example of where you'd want a foreign key to another app (versus Authors and Books) would be a foreign key pointing at the Django auth user, which is widely used. E.g. `appointment_holder = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)`

Comment: I agree with you, there are times where you need it. But attaching yourself to a django.contrib model is more okay since all Django installations comes with the Django Usermodel.