# How to import a value inside another class model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

My first app
#shope/models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Product(models.Model):
     PN  = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = "AAAA")
```

##My second app

Ship/models.py

> ```
> from shop.models import Product
> class OrderItem(models.Model):
>    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='ship_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
>    PN = models.ForeignKey(Product.PN, related_name='ship_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
>    print(PN)
> ```

All I want to do is to get PN from shope/models.py into Ship/models.py then print it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Foreign key from one app into another in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323763/foreign-key-from-one-app-into-another-in-django)

Answer (score 2):

First of all `print(PN)` makes no sense because you're printing field class instead of record (model instance) field value. Second thing is that you already have a foreign key to `Product` model and there is no reason to have another one to a specific field of same model (also I don't think this will actually work). If you want to get all related products `PN` field values, then you simply can use FK relations by `related_name`:

```
OrderItem.objects.get(id=whatever_record_id_you_need).ship_items.all().values_list('PN', flat=True)
```

Comment: I am trying to display the part number on django admin page inside the ship.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but didn't work. I want to display the PN value which is in shope/models.py in Ship/models.py so I can display the part number inside the shipping link on the admin page.

Comment: In this case you need to create a method to get `PN` (multiple?) and add this method to `read_only_fields` and fields list in admin.

Comment: Sure how can I create the get method to get the PN? Sorry I am still learning about this so I am confused.